# Find maximum date in each group with an extra condition on a different variables. get an error Max()& not defined for Date objects

Tags: r

This is the example data I have:

```
t<- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), measureX =c(1,2,1,3,1,1), date=c('2021-1-1','2021-1-2','2021-1-3','2021-1-4','2021-1-5','2021-1-6'))
t$date <- as.Date(t$date)
```

I want to identify the maximum date in each group with an extra condition on another variable while preserving the structure of the data. In my real data problem, the condition could be varied, so I can not just subset the dataset to solve the problem. Plus, I need the identified maximum date to construct other functions, so filtering data is not a good option even for this example, it works.
This is the code I tried, but got an error '& not defined for Date objects'

```
t%>%group_by(id) %>% max(t$measureX==1 & t$date)
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `max()` takes a vector, not a logical statement as its argument. So we'll use `filter()` to do our logic.

Second, `t` is a `data.frame` so you need to use `max` inside the `summarize()` (or `summarise()`, depending on spelling preferences) command.

```
t<- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), measureX =c(1,2,1,3,1,1), date=c('2021-1-1','2021-1-2','2021-1-3','2021-1-4','2021-1-5','2021-1-6'))
t$date <- as.Date(t$date)


t %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(measureX == 1) %>% #condition on another variable
  summarize(max(date))
```

(When using pipes, you don't need the `t$` prefixes.)

Update - if we need to identify the maximum date within a group based on a condition and then use that variable later, we can use this code.

```
t %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(max_date_given_condition = max(date[measureX == 1])) %>% 
  ungroup() #to be safe
```

Comment: Thank you. I made this example. In my data I really need to find the maximum value based on a condition on another variable. This condition could be varied in real situation. so not always ==1 like in the example. Which means I can not always do a filter beforehand.

Comment: Even in this simple example, when I tried max(t$measureX==1 & t$id), it works. But when I change it to  max(t$measureX==1 & t$date), it gives an error.

Comment: You can't provide a logical (`measureX == 1 & date`) inside of `max()`

I think your next question is: How can I dynamically filter my data? (or filter it differently for different groups!)

Comment: I actually need the maximum date based on a condition then use the maximum date to do other things. So I can not do a lot of filtering of the dataset.

Comment: Huzzah for comments and iterations and answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

t <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
               measureX = c(1,2,1,3,1,1), 
               date = c('2021-1-1','2021-1-2','2021-1-3','2021-1-4','2021-1-5','2021-1-6'))

t %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(max(date))
```

Comment: I don't think this "conditions on another variable".

Comment: Ah - missed that portion. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. But I want max (date & measureX==1), there is an additional conditional in the max(), which was not working for now.

Comment: Yep, looks like @dyrland added a line for the filtration

Comment: I just used this code for a project I'm working on and it works well.  When the sample dataset is generated, I used `class ()` and `typeof()` and found noticed that date variable is a character.  When we go to the next lines of code, the date variable is converted to a date using `ymd()`.  But if the date variable is already formatted as a date, then we don't need to use `mutate`.